# ¿Por qué al usar el método find() de angular solo funciona para ciertos casos?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo el siguiente formulario para agregar datos a una tabla llamada **PRODUCTO** en la BD, lo que quiero validar es que al ingresar en el input **ID Producto** se valide si esa clave no existe ya en dicha tabla, si existe que se mande un mensaje de error que diga "Registro duplicado" y que no deje insertar, sino que se inserte correctamente.

esa validacion la estoy agregando en el método agregar() de mi component.ts  y estoy usando el metodo find para encontrar si la clave que ingresé ya se encuentra en la lista de registros de la tabla y ya lo hace, pero no para todos los casos

html

```
<form [formGroup]="nuevoProductoForm">
    
    <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                            <mat-label>Id Producto:</mat-label>
                            <input matInput formControlName="IdProducto">
                            <mat-error *ngIf="nuevoProductoForm.controls.cveProducto.hasError('required')">Debe introducir la clave del producto</mat-error>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="nuevoProductoForm.controls.cveProducto.hasError('maxlength')">El tamaño máximo para este campo es de 8</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                            <mat-label>Descripción</mat-label>
                            <textarea  matInput formControlName="descripcion" class="textareaInput"></textarea>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="nuevoProductoForm.controls.descProducto.hasError('required')">Debe introducir la descripción</mat-error>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="nuevoProductoForm.controls.descProducto.hasError('maxlength')">El tamaño máximo para este campo es de 250</mat-error>
                        
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                            <mat-label>Comentarios</mat-label>
                            <textarea  matInput formControlName="comentarios" class="textareaInput"></textarea>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="nuevoProductoForm.controls.descProducto.hasError('required')">Debe introducir la descripción</mat-error>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="nuevoProductoForm.controls.descProducto.hasError('maxlength')">El tamaño máximo para este campo es de 250</mat-error>
                        
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
    </table>
            <div class="buttons">
                <button mat-button (click)="agregar()">Agregar</button>
                <button mat-button (click)="restablecer()">Restablecer</button>
            </div>
        
</form>
```

Component.ts

```
nuevoProductoForm: FormGroup;
  
  productoModel: Producto = new Producto();
  IdProducto = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(8)]);
  descripcion = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(250)]);
  comentarios = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(250)]);
  tablaProducto: Producto[] = [];


  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NuevoProductoComponent>, private productService: CatProductsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nuevoProductoForm = new FormGroup({
      IdProducto: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(8)]),
      descripcion: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(250)]),
      comentarios: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
    
  }
  
  agregar() {
    if (this.nuevoProductoForm.valid) {
      
      //servicio que trae la lista de la tabla para validar si ya existe el idProdcto
      this.productService.obtenerLista().subscribe(response => {
        this.tablaProducto = response.data;
        var existeIdProducto = this.tablaProducto.find(item => item.idProducto == this.nuevoProductoForm.get('idProducto')?.value)

    
        if (existeIdProducto) {
          console.log("YA EXISTE ");
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Error',
            text: 'Registro duplicado'
          });
        } else {
          console.log("NO EXISTE ");

          this.productoModel.idProducto = this.nuevoProductoForm.get('idProducto')?.value;
          this.productoModel.descripcion = this.nuevoProductoForm.get('descripcion')?.value;
          this.productoModel.comentarios = this.nuevoProductoForm.get('comentarios')?.value;
          this.productService.agregarNuevoProducto(this.productoModel).subscribe(response => {
            this.productoModel = response;
            Swal.fire({
              icon: 'success',
              title: 'Éxito',
              text: 'Nuevo registro guardado correctamente'
            });

          });
        }
      });



    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Debes llenar todos los campos correctamente',
        confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
      });
    }
  }
```

en la tabla **PRODUCTO** hay registros donde el idProducto tiene el maximo de caracteres que son los 8 y otros donde son menos del maximo

{idProducto: '11234543', descripcion: 'EE', comentarios: 'aaa',  …}

{idProducto: '18X1    ', descripcion: 'Swaps 18', comentarios: 'prueba', …}

cuando valido ingresando este mismo id de registro  **11234543** si me manda el mensaje de que ya existe, pero si pruebo ingresando el segundo  **18X1** entra al else que dice NO EXISTE, pero es por que solo tiene 4 caracteres y 4 espacios en blanco  y yo solo le mando los primeros 4, entonces como puedo hacer para que si me haga la validación, o como le agregaria esos caracteres que le estan faltando para que haga la validación correctamente ?

Comment: Porque tienes un espacio al final del `'18X1 '` https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4M6N.png

Comment: Y cómo puedo eliminar ese espacio en blanc?

Comment: @Root93 usando el método _trim()_

Comment: Agregando, `var` desde hace tiempo que se está desaconsejando su uso y en su lugar usar solamente `const` y `let`

Comment: @René gracias ya lo cambie a let

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

El problema con tu código es que tienes un espacio en blanco que sobra en el identificador del producto.

En concreto, el fallo está aquí

```js
var existeIdProducto = this.tablaProducto.find(item => item.idProducto == this.nuevoProductoForm.get('idProducto')?.value)
```

Para solucionarlo, puedes usar el método [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), en concreto, reemplazaremos esta línea, poniendo un `.trim()` al final.

> El método `trim()` elimina los espacios en blanco en ambos extremos del string. Los espacios en blanco en este contexto, son todos los caracteres sin contenido (espacio, tabulación, etc.) y todos los caracteres de nuevas lineas (LF,CR,etc.).
> (Fuente original: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim))

Quedaría así

```js
var existeIdProducto = this.tablaProducto.find(item => item.idProducto == this.nuevoProductoForm.get('idProducto')?.value.trim())
```

El cambio que hice fue añadir `trim()`

```js
value.trim()
```

> **Ten en cuenta** que el método `trim()` **NO es de Angular**. Mas bien, es un método nativo de JavaScript.

Si deseas profundizar más, puedes revisar la [documentación de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

Comment: Gracias, si me funciono :)